# How to transpose info in rows into one column in R?

Tags: r

I have 150 stops (Cod) and each one of this have a number of service that used.

```
|        Cod |  SERVICE1 | SERVICE2 | SERVICE3 | Position
------------------------------------------------------
| P05        |     XRS10 |     XRS07|     XRS05| 12455
| R07        |      FR05 |          |          | 4521
| X05        |     XRS07 |     XRS10|          | 57541
```

I need to put all the services (SERVICE1,SERVICE2,SERVICE3) in one column. That means that I need the following result.

```
|        Cod |   SERVICE |  Position
------------------------------------------------------
| P05        |     XRS10 |   12455
| P05        |     XRS07 |   12455
| P05        |     XRS05 |   12455
| R07        |      FR05 |    4521
| X05        |     XRS07 |   57541
| X05        |     XRS10 |   57541
```

There is any way to do this using the `sqldf` package of R. Or any kind of way to do it?

Comment: Could you please include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)  of the data, perhaps using `dput()`?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
library(magrittr) ##used for the pipe, %>%
library(dplyr) ##for filtering observations and selecting columns
library(tidyr) ##for making your dataset long/tidy

new_data <- original_data %>%
tidyr::gather(key = service_type, value = SERVICE) %>%
dplyr::filter(!is.na(SERVICE)) %>%
dplyr::select(-service_type)
```

Unfortunately I am not familiar with `sqldf`

Note that if you want to keep the information on whether the service comes from `SERVICE1`, `SERVICE2`, or `SERVICE3`, you'll omit the last line (`dplyr::select`) entirely.